# Output of mysqldump all-databases failed to run in MySQL 8.0 because of dropping the 'mysql' database

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql8

## Problem statement

`mysqldump --add-drop-database --all-database` 
creates a dump that contains

```
....
/*!40000 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mysql`*/;
....
```

This is expected and I believe is a correct behavior.

Yet, if cat'ing this dump into a mysql server, i.e. `cat dump | mysql -u root -pxxxx`  (The account has SUPER), it complains `ERROR 3552 (HY000) at line 30: Access to system schema 'mysql' is rejected.`

## Question

Is there any way to make it works, without manually editing the dump.
Or sed/grep to remove the offending line is my only choice?

This used to be working in MySQL 5.6 (i.e. it accept dropping the mysql database)

The root account has the follow privileges `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE, BACKUP_ADMIN, RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN, XA_RECOVER_ADMIN`

Server and Client: MySQL 8.0.12

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need to dump/restore the `mysql` database schema.

If you want an automated method which skips the `mysql` database (or any other database you **don't** want to dump) without specifying every single database, check the answer
to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/any-option-for-mysqldump-to-ignore-databases-for-backup) for a simple script to autmatically get all databases except those you want to ignore.

Comment: I want to restore mysql table though - specifically the users and roles. I was trying to initialize the a slave server.

Comment: @HelloSam is it viable to script TWO dumps, one with `add-drop-database` and one without, then restore them one after the another?

Comment: that's kinda works - except I cannot use --all-database and have to find out what database in my master besides the `mysql` and list them out in the one with --add-drop's.